# Magento configurable custom product prices with no prices pattern

Tags: magento, product, configure

Here is what i'm trying to do:
I have a product (a picture). This picture can be sold on paper or canvas and have multiple dimensions.
I have created an configurable product for this but the prices are messed up.
If the product have on paper surface the dimension: 66x66 cm that is set to be sold on $100 , then i have to set +$0 for paper option and +$100 for 66x66 dimension. (paper - 66x66 = $100 )
The problem is here, when i need to set the the canvas surface  at the same dimension. 
If the total price needs to be $125 (canvas - 66x66 = $125) the only way i can make it is to set the canvas at +$25 and to use the available option that i set before.

If i have multiple options for at some point i have to change the price for some dimensions that were set up already and this will affect all products. This is the problem, all prices will be messed up.

How i can set easily custom prices for any option that product must have?...becouse the prices doesn't have any patterns?

prices example:

**for paper**

X-SMALL 51cm X 51cm $ 180.00

SMALL 61cm X 61cm   $ 216.00

MEDIUM 82cm X 82cm  $ 288.00

LARGE 91 cm X 91 cm $ 320.00

**for canvas**

X-SMALL     51cm X 51cm $ 220.00

SMALL     61cm X 61cm   $ 265.00

MEDIUM 82cm X 82cm  $ 350.00

LARGE 91 cm X 91 cm $ 395.00

X-LARGE 102x102 cm  $ 442.00

...these prices are for 1 product. remember: there is no prices pattern based on size and printed surface.

Any idea is highly appreciated.Thanks so much.

Comment: Probably belongs in the Magento Stack Exchange http://magento.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this, and it's a little janky, is to create a custom "Size and Materials" attribute.  This attribute's value will be a unique string that represents both the size and the materials of your products -- this will let you set a price differential.  Create a master configuration product that uses this attribute as the "configurable" one (instead of the separate size and materials attributes).  This will let you set the price differentials for all your products.

The other option is to look into one of the many extensions that claims to [allow simple product prices to be used in place of the configurable product price](https://www.google.com/search?q=magento+configurable+product+use+simple+product+price&oq=magento+configurable+product+use+simple+product+price&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4j69i64.9333j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8).